# Should my custom component descend from TDataModule?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to build a custom component that manages a bunch of operations and fire several events. I will need to manage a database connection and several other design time components. (TQuery, TTable, etc) I would like to use the IDE interface to set some of these obects up.

Ideas:

1. Does inheriting from a DataModule in same way give me a place to put
   these components when I'm designing the component? (I suspect not,
   but is there a way to have my CustomComponent behave as a DataModule
   when designing it, but not when it's used?)
2. Should I have my custom component simply descend from TComponent, but contain a 
   TDataModule object and add the components I need to it?
3. Should I be bagging this concept and just create the components I need manually?
4. Your solution cause you're smarter than me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, for one simple reason: There's a bug in the IDE in Delphi XE that causes the form designer to treat classes that inherit from TDataModule as if they inherited from TForm instead.  This means that a bunch of TForm-related properties will get written to your DFM, which will end up raising an exception at runtime when it tries to load the data modules.

If it wasn't for this bug, that would be a fine idea.

Comment: Would you then suggest something like option 2?  To get Delpi's design time benefits while designing my custom component, have my custom component use a data module?

Comment: @EricG: Yeah, that would probably be a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you forget trying to design the component visually at all.  It is a non-visual component, so just derive it from `TComponent` and have it create/manage the DB components as needed.  No need to use a `TDataModule` at all.  That should be reserved for end users to use in their own projects, not for component authors to use in their non-visual components.

Comment: Well in this case, I am the creator and the end user.  I'm just trying to make my code as easy to reuse as possible.

Comment: "No need to use a `TDataModule` at all. That should be reserved for end users to use in their own projects, not for component authors to use in their non-visual components."

There seems to be a lot of support for this idea.  Can you explain to me why I shouldn't use a `TDataModule` inside a component?

Comment: Because it is wasted overhead for the component itself, and AFAIK there is no way for a component to take advantage of the IDEs's built-in design-time editor for an embedded DataModule. That only works for DataModules that the IDE itself manages for a project. If you want to visually design the contents of your component, you would have to create your own design-time editor that manipulates a component instance as needed.